# CVRPTW variant on optaplanner with load time in each customer

Tags: optaplanner

I'd like to add following restrictions to the CVRPTW problem, and know if it can be modeled on optaplanner:

1) Vehicles start in a garage, loaded in the customers and unloaded in a depot. After last unload, return to the garage

2) In each customer,  the vehicle has a different volume to load, and a different time duration for the loading.

TW restrictions is global, every vehicles should start at time x and return to the garage at most on time z.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VRP examples in optaplanner-examples, it already has capacity and serviceDuration per `TimeWinowedCustomer`. All vehicles also return to the depot (= garage).

The only thing I see missing is an arrivalTimeBackAtTheDepot for a Vehicle, which is straightforward to calculate from the last customer's departureTime for each vehicle.